# Traceback Error running 'pipenv shell' version 2018.11.26 - bug supposed to be fixed

Tags: python, virtual, python-3.7, environment, pipenv

I keep on getting a traceback error running pipenv shell on version 2018.11.26, for python 3.7.

I keep on getting [this error](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/622) when running `pipenv shell` on version 2018.11.26, for python 3.7. I looked here, but it seems like a bug that should have been fixed, so perhaps this points to another problem.

I tried `pipenv lock` to update pipenv and `pipenv --rm` to remove pipenv and reinstall `pipenv install`

with `pipenv check`, I get a similar traceback error with

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) at the end.
```

```
pipenv shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 390, in shell
    pypi_mirror=state.pypi_mirror,
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2156, in do_shell
    three=three, python=python, validate=False, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "c:\users\lilyx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 590, in ensure_project
    crayons.green(shorten_path(path_to_python)),
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```